# Displaying layered image in mPDF

Tags: php, imagick, mpdf

I was using Imagick layered image to generate images on my project.

```
$image = new \Imagick(); //init

//add layers
$url = '...'; //layer's url
$layer = new \Imagick(realpath($url));
$image->addImage($layer);

$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$result = $image->mergeImageLayers(13);
echo $result->getImageBlob(); //echo final image url
```

I'm trying to generate pdf file with mPDF (6.1) in Magento 1.9.3.
The Imagick script return image url. and I echo them to a img tag in the phtml template

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'mpdf/mpdf.php');
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
$block->setTemplate('filename.phtml');

$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($block->toHtml());
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

The error show "Error parsing image file - image type not recognised, and not supported by GD imagecreate"

I have no idea why it doesn't work.
If I paste the generated image url to a new tab, it works fine.
I appreciated any help possible. Thank you

Comment: `$result->getImageBlob();` does not return image URL but image data as a binary string. To display them direcly to HTML, you have to convert them to base64 and use base64 notation in src, or save them to file and link the file.

Comment: "Error parsing image file - image type not recognised, and not supported by GD imagecreate" - maybe show where that error is coming from.